# Multi part form - trying to stop default a href behaviour

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

Having my first go at a multi-part form with forward and backward controls. The initial idea is you can't jump off the page until you've completed all required fields. I'm using multiple `a hrefs` to submit the form, one set of these `a hrefs` is part of menu which is included in form pages and none form pages. So my thinking was to use javascript, read the pageId placed in the  tag to decide whether after clicking on the href it should be submitted as a form or simply follow the default href="" link. So I tried the following:

```
        function setvalue(whatvalue){

            alert (document.getElementById('subtype').value);

            if (pageId != "gettingstarted"){
                alert ("Doesn't equal gettingstarted so submit");
                if (whatvalue){document.getElementById('subtype').value=whatvalue;}
                $('#myForm').submit();
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Using these  links with the default href="" and an onclick firing the js function

```
     <a onclick="setvalue('gettingstarted.php');" href="gettingstarted.php">Get Started</a>
     <a onclick="setvalue('form1.php');" href="form1.php">Form One</a>
     <a onclick="setvalue('form2.php');" href="form2.php">Form Two</a>
     <a onclick="setvalue('preview.php');" href="preview.php">Preview</a>
```

You click the href, then if it's not the start page (containing no form), there's a tweak to the form and it is then submitted and the default href="" is stopped from being carried out (by the return false;). If is the start page the js does nothing and in theory the href link is then followed.

The href links though are not being stopped. If I change the hrefs to "#" it works, as I can see a flicker in which the page loads and then php form checker kicks in. But with the links in place, the link location is loaded in and the submit (and subsequent form check) doesn't appear to have the chance to happen. Read a few threads relating to stopping default  behaviour and thought the return false was the answer.

Thanks for your time and reading.

Answer (score 0):

the event needs to have a return in the attribute

```
 <a onclick="return setvalue('gettingstarted.php');" ..... />
```

you also need to add a return true here which will allow the event to continue.

```
function setvalue(whatvalue){

            alert (document.getElementById('subtype').value);

            if (pageId != "gettingstarted"){
                alert ("Doesn't equal gettingstarted so submit");
                if (whatvalue){document.getElementById('subtype').value=whatvalue;}
                $('#myForm').submit();
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
```